# How to undo usermod -e?

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

I used the command

```
usermod -e YYYY_MM_DD user
```

Now, the user's account is expired.

What command can I put in order to remove the expiration date on the user account?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can undo it by running `usermod -e` again, this time passing an empty string in place of the `EXPIRE_DATE` string ex.

```
sudo usermod -e '' user
```

From `man usermod`:

> ```
>    -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
>        The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is
>        specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD.
>
>        An empty EXPIRE_DATE argument will disable the expiration of the
>        account.
> ```